# How to get a list of all known classes?

Tags: random, entity

I'd like a function that returns a stringified entity at random. I can't seem to find a full list of classes from which to sample:

[image]

Comment: `EntityValue[]`?

Comment: Huh wasn’t obvious to me

Comment: Shouldn’t it be $EntityClasses or EntityClass[All] or something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a list of entity types as follows (see the last bullet in the details section of the documentation of EntityValue):

```
EntityValue[] //Short
```

> {AdministrativeDivision,Aircraft,Airline,Airport,<<288>>,YogaPosition,YogaProp,YogaSequence,ZIPCode}

Note that in the entity framework, classes are collections of entities from a single entity type. For example, "GroupOf8" is an entity class of the "Country" entity type.